# Grid fill empty space in scrollable area tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm buildinging a gui with a list of labels in a scrollable area. Now I want that the labels fill the empty space via grid manager. So I use the `columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` method. It works fine for the scrollbar but not for the labels inside the scrollable area. Example showing my issue:

[image: Example for my issue]

```
class app():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("341x448")
        self.root.minsize(340,440)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def display(self):
        self.container = ttk.Frame(self.root)
        self.container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.container)

        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.container, orient = tk.VERTICAL, command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)


        self.scrollable_frame.bind(
            "<Configure>",
            lambda e: self.canvas.configure(
                scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = self.scrollable_frame, anchor = "nw")
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)



        for i in range(15):
            Label = ttk.LabelFrame(self.scrollable_frame, text = "Sample scrolling label")
            Label.grid(row = i, column = 0,  columnspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)
            Label.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

            Button = ttk.Button(Label, text=f"Button {i}")
            Button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NW)

        self.container.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nswe')
        scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "ns")


        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    start = app()
    start.display()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why your labels do not fill the horizontal space:

1. You grid the labels in `self.scrollable_frame` but you have not configured its grid to expand. You need to add

   ```
     self.scrollable_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
   ```
2. You have not set the width and height of `self.scrollable_frame` when you put it in the canvas, so by default, it stays the size it needs to display all its content. If you want it to expand to fill all the space available in the canvas, you can bind the canvas resizing event to a function that will resize the frame accordingly. So add

   ```
    self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
   ```

   in `self.display()` and create the `self.resize()` function

   ```
   def resize(self, event):
        w = self.scrollable_frame.winfo_reqwidth()
        h = self.scrollable_frame.winfo_reqheight()
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(1, width=max(w, event.width), height=max(h, event.height))
   ```

   that makes the frame expand if the canvas is larger than the minimum size required to display all the widgets.

By the way, I suggest you to follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide, especially for names, e.g. capitalize class names but not variable names. And above all, be consistent, it will make the code clearer and easier to understand. In particular, I find using `Label` and `Button` as variable names quite confusing as they are class names in tkinter.

Comment: Your answer helps a lot. Thanks!
 With the vertical arrow I wanted to show that the grid manager works fine in this direction. But yes it is a bit confusing.

Comment: @lu3si Ok, great. I was not sure whether you wanted to change something ín the vertical spacing too.